# RabbitMQ perfomance issue

Tags: java, performance, rabbitmq

I have an app which receives messages from some producer using RabbitMQ, parses them and sends somwhere else. The problem is that my app doesn't use the CPU power fully. it uses not more than 25% of the CPU. look at this screenshot from profiler:
[image]

Here is the code in which the biggest part of the processing executing:

```
public class Consumer {

    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "MdnaMessagesQueue";
    private static int i = 1;
    private final ConnectionFactory factory;
    private final boolean autoAck = false;
    private final Connection connection;
    private final Channel channel;
    private String response;
    private Sender sender;
    private Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class);
    private ExecutorService es;


    public Consumer() throws IOException{
        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        connection = factory.newConnection(es);
        channel = connection.createChannel();
        sender = new Sender();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
        channel.basicQos(25);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream("/home/mikhail/bzrrep/DLP/DLPServer/src/main/java/log4j.properties"));
        } catch (Exception e){
            LOG.error(e);
        }
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
    }

    /**
     * is used to receive messages from the queue
     * @param customerId the id of current customer
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public void receive(final String customerId) throws IOException,InterruptedException{




        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");



        final QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, autoAck, "myConsumerTag",
                new DefaultConsumer(channel){
                    @Override
                    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                                               Envelope envelope,
                                               AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                               byte[] body)
                            throws IOException{                           
                        BasicProperties replyProperties = new BasicProperties.Builder().correlationId(properties.getCorrelationId()).build();
                        long deliveryTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
                        try{
                            LOG.info(" [" +(i++) +"] Received from first queue ");
                            byte[] dataArr = body;
                            MimeParser mimeParser = new MimeParser(true);
                            Filter filter = new Filter();
                            ByteArrayInputStream bais1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataArr);
                            MessageInfo mi = mimeParser.parseMessages(bais1);
                            //checking for compliance with rules
                            boolean messageAccepted = filter.getMessageAcceptability(mi.getPlainText(), customerId);
                            response = filter.getResult();
                            if(messageAccepted){
                                //sending to the other queue
                                sender.send(dataArr);
                                channel.basicPublish("", properties.getReplyTo(), replyProperties, response.getBytes());//need to add responce
                            } else {
                                channel.basicPublish("", properties.getReplyTo(), replyProperties, response.getBytes());
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            LOG.error(e);
                        }finally {
                            channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Here is the snapshot from the profiler:
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the Qos ? Did it affect your CPU utilization ?

Comment: nope. this didn't help. I even thought that it has made it slower

Comment: maybe your app can't utilize 100% CPU because it just doesn't contain heavy operations?, btw, how much cores does your machine have? If 4 than you app utilize only one core.

Comment: @zaq178miami 8 cores. and logically it must utilise more CPU time if it'll receive more messages. And as I see it can't receive more than 100 messages per second.

Comment: Are wrote multicore consumer? Btw, broker itself may limit consumption/publishing speed (reason my vary, for example - resource limits). Can you publish config you are using for RabbitMQ? TL;DR; I had mythical problems a lot with ubuntu family, so can you just try some centos or other distro in virtuabox, for example, and compare performance? P.S.: Can you run 10 instances and look on resources usage with top?

Comment: what you mean by multicore consumer? I didn't create multiple threads in which call the consumer if you are talking about that. As for limiting consumption by the broker because of the resource limits I'm not shure. I guess it has enough resources. config? where can I find it? it's quite difficult to realise it in the virtual box for me as I'm not familiar with it. to run multiple instances is difficult too because tomcat use concrete ports for this and deny possibility of running multiple instances

Comment: I think that in one thread one consumer live on one core, so in you monitoring it may looks like like it eat just some %. Without clear numbers and stats you can't even say that you have a problem. Config should be in default location for your system. For most linuxes it should be /etc/rabbitmq/<some files here>. Try to monitor RabbitMQ via management plugin via web interface http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

Comment: there is the path /etc/rabbitmq/ but there no config files there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32880/discussion-between-zaq178miami-and-nikitin-mikhail)